Como puedo solucionar un error al renderizar en Angular, me dice que mi variable no tiene tal propiedad, es decir undefined
Tengo un servicio que hace las consultas y utiliza observables, no sé por qué cuando quiero renderizar en el HTML me aparece el error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'common')
Tengo la sospecha de que el renderizado se hace más rápido que la respuesta del servicio. Ya que si me regresa la respuesta que espero, que es un objeto "pais" que se imprime en consola.
Este es el código del componente:
export class VerPaisComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute,
    private paisService : PaisService
    ) {}
    
    pais!: Country;
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      
    this.activatedRoute.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap(({id}) => this.paisService.getPaisPorId(id)),
        tap(console.log)  //Imprime la respuesta
        )
      .subscribe(pais => {
        this.pais = pais;
      });
    } 
}

El servicio:
export class PaisService {

  private apiUrl: string = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  buscarPais(termino: string):Observable<Country[]>{

    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/name/${termino}`;
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(url);
  }

  getPaisPorId(id: string):Observable<Country>{
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/alpha/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Country>(url);
  }
}

El HTML:
<div *ngIf="!pais; else divPais" class="alert alert-info">
    Espere por favor ...
</div>

<ng-template #divPais>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p>{{pais.name.common}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

Espero puedan orientarme, gracias.

Podrías poner la respuesta que dices que te da el servicio para que veamos que intentas pintar?

Eso es porque el endpoint retorna el país dentro de un arreglo. Puedes corregirlo así:
Modificando el tipo de retorno a Country[]
getPaisPorId(id: string):Observable<Country[]>{
     const url = `${this.apiUrl}/alpha/${id}`;
     return this.http.get<Country[]>(url);
}

Asignando el primer elemento del arreglo:
.subscribe(pais => {
        this.pais = pais[0] // validar que no esté vacío;
      });


Reconozco el código del curso de Angular de Fernando Herrera, la cuestión es que el API regresa un arreglo, usa Postman para probarlos y ver que regresa. Modificando quedaría así:
Componente
  pais?: Country;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private paisService: PaisService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.activatedRoute.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap( ({ id }) => this. paisService.searchCountryById( id )),
      )
      .subscribe( country => {
        if ( !country ) return this.router.navigateByUrl('');
        return this.pais = country;
      });
  }

Servicio
  searchCountryById(id: string): Observable<Country | null> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/alpha/${id}`;

    return this.http.get<Country[]>(url).pipe(
      map((countries) => (countries.length > 0 ? countries[0] : null)),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }

Lo que map hace es tomar el array de países y devolver el primer país si el array tiene al menos un país (countries.length > 0 ? countries[0] : null). Si el array está vacío, devuelve null. Agregamos un catchError para atrapar cualquier error, si tuvieras un manejo de errores más complejo podrías crear un método y reemplazar of(null).
